# select rows if one column equals sum of other two

Tags: oracle

I was trying to select a particular record, which satisfies the condition if `column1 =  column2 + column3`

```
SELECT gtt_id ,
  column1,
  SUM(NVL(column2, 0) + NVL(column3, 0)) AS total
FROM my_table where column1 = total
GROUP BY gtt_id,
column1;
```

I am getting the following error:

`ORA-00904: "TOTAL": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use total in the same query ,for that you need to wrap the query and use that in outer loop.

```
SELECT gtt_id,column1,total
FROM
(
SELECT gtt_id ,
      column1,
      SUM(NVL(column2, 0) + NVL(column3, 0))  total
FROM my_table 
--where column1 = total
GROUP BY gtt_id,
column1
)
where column1 = total;
```